# I installed pydicom through pip but it somehow cannot be found when I try to import the library. Could someone give a suggestion to fix this?

Tags: python, eclipse, pip, pydicom

Please see this screenshot:

[image: screenshot 1]

Isn't the package pydicom already installed?

Credit to Igor:
It looks like that it's working in Sublime Text 2's build using "import dicom". However it is still somehow not working in my Eclipse with PyDev environment.

---

***I have solved the problem in Eclipse after adding a path in the Python Interpreter configuration by hand (Somehow Auto-Config didn't add this path.).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the result of `pip show pydicom`?

Comment: It shows the following: Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: pydicom
Version: 0.9.9
Summary: Pure python package for DICOM medical file reading and writing
Home-page: http://pydicom.googlecode.com
Author: Darcy Mason and contributors
Author-email: darcymason@gmail.com
License: MIT license
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:

Comment: Use `import dicom` instead of pydicom.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same series of steps and saw the same issue. After digging around it looks like the package appears as "dicom". Try this instead:

```
import dicom
```

Edit: Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119684/parse-dicom-files-in-native-python) mentioning this library, everyone is importing it this way too.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like that it's working in Sublime Text 2's build using "import dicom". However it is still somehow not working in my Eclipse with PyDev environment.

Comment: Hmm, try re-starting your Eclipse/clearing cache. What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
python -m pip freeze
```

Is the package there? If not, you have installed it for the wrong python environment. I suggest you install it as follows:

In Bash prompt (terminal):

```
python -m pip install pydicom
```

You can change `python` with `python3` or the absolute address of the executable. If you don't know the absolute address of the executable, you can obtain it as follows:

In Bash prompt (terminal):

```
which python
```

(or `python3`). The output would be the absolute path, which you may utilise like so:

```
/Users/xyz/bin/python -m pip install pydicom
```

Finally, if you want to find out the path to your executable from within Python, you may do so like this:

```
from sys import executable
print(executable)
```

The output will be the absolute path to the current environment's interpreter.